# Taking average of linear regression results

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sample-size, p-value, mean

Say I have a very large sample of observations, like a thousand of them, and I want to do (multiple) linear regression on them, i.e., regressing the response variable on the predictors. Now instead of doing so, I would randomly sample a subset of that large sample (say half of it, or a third of it, or even a fourth) and do regression analysis on that subset only. So I do this for $n$ times and each time I have a set of results, like coefficient estimates, $p$-values, etc. Finally I take the average of all the $n$ independent sets of results to get the final regression results.

The question is: Would this rather "awkward" method be equivalent to the straightforward one (doing regression on all the observations that I have)? By "equivalent" I mean the coefficient estimates (signs and magnitudes) and $p$-values resulted from the two methods are the same, or insignificantly different.

My second question is, as we all know, that in order to have a good regression analysis, it is often required to have a sufficiently large number of observations. What about the other way round? If I have too large a sample, like thousands of observations, should I just fit them all or should I sample a subset from it and fit?

Comment: The answer appears in [your previous thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/regression-on-means-of-log-transformed-variables): the methods are not equivalent. Consider, too, that a few thousand observations is by no means "large." But your final question looks worthy of consideration: what should be done when you have so many observations that they are more than you need and more than your computer can cope with? The answers depend partly on the purpose of the regression: is it for exploration, testing hypotheses, prediction, or perhaps something else?

Comment: First question: Your method sounds like some sort of bootstrap; these methods are well developed and there is a huge literature on them. Probably the most common reason for using a bootstrap is that there is not a good existing estimate of the variance of whatever you are trying to estimate. Why are you suggesting this method instead of the usual one? What are you hoping to learn or gain from doing this? Second question: 1000 is by no means a "large" number of observations these days. If you had many millions or billions of observations, you might want to sample to cut down on running time, bu

Comment: The coefficients will all be estimates of the same population parameters, and averages of them would eventually converge to the whole-sample estimates but the p-values won't 'average' in the way you suggest. It's not clear quite what you intend by 'insignificantly different' though.